# Why is Entity Framework Core attempting to insert records into one of the tables from many to many relationships and NOT the join table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Given the following set up where there are many `Teams` and there are many `LeagueSessions`. Each `Team` belongs to zero or more `LeagueSessions` but only ever one `LeagueSession` is active. `LeagueSessions` have many teams, and the teams will be repeated. Many-to-many relationship is established between `Teams` and `LeagueSessions` with a join table called `TeamsSessions`.

`Team` model looks like this:

```
public class Team
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public League League { get; set; }
        public string LeagueID { get; set; }        
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TeamSession> TeamsSessions { get; set; }
    }
```

Team model fluent api configuration:

```
`
public class TeamConfiguration
    {        
        public TeamConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> model)
        {
            // The data for this model will be generated inside ThePLeagueDataCore.DataBaseInitializer.DatabaseBaseInitializer.cs class
            // When generating data for models in here, you have to provide it with an ID, and it became mildly problematic to consistently get
            // a unique ID for all the teams. In ThePLeagueDataCore.DataBaseInitializer.DatabaseBaseInitializer.cs we can use dbContext to generate
            // unique ids for us for each team.

            model.HasOne(team => team.League)
                .WithMany(league => league.Teams)
                .HasForeignKey(team => team.LeagueID);   
        }

    }
`
```

Each team belongs to a single `League`. League model looks like this:

```
`public class League
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }        
        public string SportTypeID { get; set; }
        public SportType SportType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LeagueSessionSchedule> Sessions { get; set; }

    }`
```

fluent API for the `League`:

```
`public LeagueConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<League> model)
        {
            model.HasOne(league => league.SportType)
                .WithMany(sportType => sportType.Leagues)
                .HasForeignKey(league => league.SportTypeID);

            model.HasMany(league => league.Teams)
                .WithOne(team => team.League)
                .HasForeignKey(team => team.LeagueID);

            model.HasData(leagues);
        }`
```

`SessionScheduleBase` class looks like this:

```
public class SessionScheduleBase
    {
        public string LeagueID { get; set; }
        public bool ByeWeeks { get; set; }
        public long? NumberOfWeeks { get; set; }
        public DateTime SessionStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime SessionEnd { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TeamSession> TeamsSessions { get; set; } = new Collection<TeamSession>();
        public ICollection<GameDay> GamesDays { get; set; } = new Collection<GameDay>();
    }
```

Note: `LeagueSessionSchedule` inherits from `SessionScheduleBase`

The `TeamSession` model looks like this:

```
`public class TeamSession
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string TeamId { get; set; }
        public Team Team { get; set; }
        public string LeagueSessionScheduleId { get; set; }
        public LeagueSessionSchedule LeagueSessionSchedule { get; set; }
    }`
```

I then configure the relationship with the fluent API like this:

```
`public TeamSessionConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<TeamSession> model)
        {

            model.HasKey(ts => new { ts.TeamId, ts.LeagueSessionScheduleId });            
            model.HasOne(ts => ts.Team)
                .WithMany(t => t.TeamsSessions)
                .HasForeignKey(ts => ts.TeamId);
            model.HasOne(ts => ts.LeagueSessionSchedule)
                .WithMany(s => s.TeamsSessions)
                .HasForeignKey(ts => ts.LeagueSessionScheduleId);
        }`
```

The problem arises whenever I attempt to insert a new `LeagueSessionSchedule`. The way I am adding a new `TeamSession` object onto the new `LeagueSessionSchedule` is like this:

```
`foreach (TeamSessionViewModel teamSession in newSchedule.TeamsSessions)
    {                 
        Team team = await this._teamRepository.GetByIdAsync(teamSession.TeamId, ct);

            if(team != null)
            {
                TeamSession newTeamSession = new TeamSession()
                {
                    Team = team,                            
                    LeagueSessionSchedule = leagueSessionSchedule
                };

                leagueSessionSchedule.TeamsSessions.Add(newTeamSession);
            }
    }`
```

Saving the new `LeagueSessionSchedule` code:

```
public async Task<LeagueSessionSchedule> AddScheduleAsync(LeagueSessionSchedule newLeagueSessionSchedule, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    this._dbContext.LeagueSessions.Add(newLeagueSessionSchedule);
    await this._dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(ct);

    return newLeagueSessionSchedule;
}
```

Saving the new `LeagueSessionSchedule` object throws an error by Entity Framework Core that it cannot INSERT a duplicate primary key value into the `dbo.Teams` table. I have no idea why its attempting to add to `dbo.Teams` table and not into `TeamsSessions` table.

ERROR:

```
INSERT INTO [LeagueSessions] ([Id], [Active], [ByeWeeks], [LeagueID], [NumberOfWeeks], [SessionEnd], [SessionStart])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);
INSERT INTO [Teams] ([Id], [Discriminator], [LeagueID], [Name], [Selected])
VALUES (@p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11),
(@p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16),
(@p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21),
(@p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26),
(@p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31),
(@p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36),
(@p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41),
(@p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46);

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Teams'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Teams'. The duplicate key value is (217e2e11-0603-4239-aab5-9e2f1d3ebc2c).
```

My goal is to create a new `LeagueSessionSchedule` object. Along with the creation of this object, I also have to create a new `TeamSession` entry to the join table (or not if join table is not necessary) to then be able to pick any given team and see what session it is currently a part of.

My entire `PublishSchedule` method is the following:

```
`
public async Task<bool> PublishSessionsSchedulesAsync(List<LeagueSessionScheduleViewModel> newLeagueSessionsSchedules, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            List<LeagueSessionSchedule> leagueSessionOperations = new List<LeagueSessionSchedule>();

            foreach (LeagueSessionScheduleViewModel newSchedule in newLeagueSessionsSchedules)
            {
                LeagueSessionSchedule leagueSessionSchedule = new LeagueSessionSchedule()
                {
                    Active = newSchedule.Active,
                    LeagueID = newSchedule.LeagueID,
                    ByeWeeks = newSchedule.ByeWeeks,
                    NumberOfWeeks = newSchedule.NumberOfWeeks,
                    SessionStart = newSchedule.SessionStart,
                    SessionEnd = newSchedule.SessionEnd                    
                };

                // leagueSessionSchedule = await this._sessionScheduleRepository.AddScheduleAsync(leagueSessionSchedule, ct);

                // create game day entry for all configured game days
                foreach (GameDayViewModel gameDay in newSchedule.GamesDays)
                {
                    GameDay newGameDay = new GameDay()
                    {
                        GamesDay = gameDay.GamesDay
                    };

                     // leagueSessionSchedule.GamesDays.Add(newGameDay);

                    // create game time entry for every game day
                    foreach (GameTimeViewModel gameTime in gameDay.GamesTimes)
                    {
                        GameTime newGameTime = new GameTime()
                        {
                            GamesTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(gameTime.GamesTime).DateTime.ToLocalTime(),
                            // GameDayId = newGameDay.Id
                        };

                        // newGameTime = await this._sessionScheduleRepository.AddGameTimeAsync(newGameTime, ct);                        
                        newGameDay.GamesTimes.Add(newGameTime);
                    }

                    leagueSessionSchedule.GamesDays.Add(newGameDay);
                }

                // update teams sessions
                foreach (TeamSessionViewModel teamSession in newSchedule.TeamsSessions)
                {
                    // retrieve the team with the corresponding id
                    Team team = await this._teamRepository.GetByIdAsync(teamSession.TeamId, ct);

                    if(team != null)
                    {
                        TeamSession newTeamSession = new TeamSession()
                        {
                            Team = team,                            
                            LeagueSessionSchedule = leagueSessionSchedule
                        };

                        leagueSessionSchedule.TeamsSessions.Add(newTeamSession);
                    }
                }

                // update matches for this session
                foreach (MatchViewModel match in newSchedule.Matches)
                {
                    Match newMatch = new Match()
                    {
                        DateTime = match.DateTime,
                        HomeTeamId = match.HomeTeam.Id,
                        AwayTeamId = match.AwayTeam.Id,
                        LeagueID = match.LeagueID                        
                    };

                    leagueSessionSchedule.Matches.Add(newMatch);
                }

                try
                {
                    leagueSessionOperations.Add(await this._sessionScheduleRepository.AddScheduleAsync(leagueSessionSchedule, ct));
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

            // ensure all leagueSessionOperations did not return any null values
            return leagueSessionOperations.All(op => op != null);
        }
`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the remaining code like how the other entities have been configured with the `EntityTypeBuilder` and how you read and save the entities. Specially where the `team` object is coming from since entity framework think it is a new object. Try to provide a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: Most likely it doesn't know that `team` already exists.  Your `team` object is probably a detached from the dbcontext so it assumes it needs to be added because you've delared it as `HasOne` requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I've added the additional code. I think this should be sufficient. Please let me k now if it is not. For the join table `TeamSession` I followed a guide on how to set up many to many relationships described here https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Comment: @O.MeeKoh What is the code for `_teamRepository` and where/how do you use the `AddScheduleAsync()` method. You show only parts of your code and leave holes in the execution path. We should see where your code starts, how the context is opened, how it reads the entities (with the helper classes you have/use), how you change the data and finally how you save them.

Comment: @ErikPhilips was correct. My dbContext class had its lifetime as transient, and when I changed it to singleton it worked just fine.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh Do not use your DbContext as a singleton, EF is not thread safe therefore you will eventually run into threading conditions.

Comment: I ended up making it scoped, after I read a couple of blog posts. Any reason why I shouldn’t have it as scoped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is not a many-to-many relationship.

It is two separate one-to-many relationships, which happen to refer to the same table on one end of the relationship.

While it is true that on the database level, both use cases are represented by three tables, i.e. `Foo  1->* FooBar *<-1 Bar`, these two cases are treated differently by Entity Framework's automated behavior - and this is very important.

EF only handles the cross table for you if it is a direct many-to-many, e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

EF handles the cross table behind the scenes, and you are never made aware of the existence of the cross table (from the code perspective).

> ***Importantly, EF Core does not yet support implicit cross tables!** There is currently no way to do this in EF Core, but even if there were, you're not using it anyway, so the answer to your problem remains the same regardless of whether you're using EF or EF Core.*

However, you have defined your own cross table. While this is still representative of a many-to-many relationship in database terms, it has ceased to be a many-to-many relationship as far as EF is concerned, and any documentation you find on EF's many-to-many relationships no longer applies to your scenario.

---

### Unattached but indirectly added objects are assumed to be new.

By "indirectly added", I mean you that it was added to the context as part of another entity (which you directly added to the context). In the following example, `foo` is directly added and `bar` is indirectly added:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();

foo.Bar = bar;

context.Foos.Add(foo);   // directly adding foo
                         // ... but not bar
context.SaveChanges();
```

When you add (and commit) a new entity to the context, EF adds it for you. However, EF also looks at any related entities that the first entity contains. During the commit in the above example, EF will look at **both** the `foo` and `bar` entities and will handle them accordingly. EF is smart enough to realize that you want `bar` to be stored in the database since you put it inside the `foo` object and you explicitly asked EF to add `foo` to the database.

It is important to realize that you've told EF that `foo` should be created (since you called `Add()`, which implies a new item), but you never told EF what it should do with `bar`. It's unclear (to EF) what you expect EF to do with this, and thus EF is left guessing at what to do.

If you never explained to EF whether `bar` already exists or not, **Entity Framework defaults to assuming it needs to create this entity in the database**.

> Saving the new LeagueSessionSchedule object throws an error by Entity Framework Core that it cannot INSERT a duplicate primary key value into the dbo.Teams table. I have no idea why its attempting to add to dbo.Teams table

Knowing what you now know, the error becomes clearer. EF is trying to add this team (which was the `bar` object in my example) because it has no information on this team object and what its state in the database is.

There are a few solutions here.

**1. Use the FK property instead of the navigational property**

This is my preferred solution because it leaves no room for error. If the team ID does not yet exist, you get an error. At no point will EF try to create a team, since it doesn't even know the team's data, it only knows the (alleged) ID you're trying to create a relationship with.

> *Note: I am omitting `LeagueSessionSchedule` as it is unrelated to the current error - but it's essentially the same behavior for both `Team` and `LeagueSessionSchedule`.*

```
TeamSession newTeamSession = new TeamSession()
{
    TeamId = team.Id                           
};
```

By using the FK property instead of the nav prop, you are informing EF that this is an **existing** team - and therefore EF no longer tries to (re)create this team.

**2. Ensure that the team is tracked by the current context**

> *Note: I am omitting `LeagueSessionSchedule` as it is unrelated to the current error - but it's essentially the same behavior for both `Team` and `LeagueSessionSchedule`.*

```
context.Teams.Attach(team);

TeamSession newTeamSession = new TeamSession()
{
    Team = team
};
```

By attaching the object to the context, you are informing it of its existence. The default state of a newly attached entity is `Unchanged`, meaning "this already exists in the database and has not been changed - so you don't need to update it when we commit the context".

If you have actually made changes to your team that you want to be updated during commit, you should instead use:

```
context.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

`Entry()` inherently also attaches the entity, and by setting its state to `Modified` you ensure that the new values will be committed to the database when you call `SaveChanges()`.

---

Note that I prefer solution 1 over solution 2 because it's foolproof and much less likely to lead to unexpected behavior or runtime exceptions.

---

### String primary keys are undesirable

I'm not going to say that it doesn't work, but strings cannot be autogenerated by Entity Framework, making them undesirable as the type of your entity's PK. You will need to manually set your entity PK values.

Like I said, it's not impossible, but your code shows that you're not explicitly setting PK values:

```
if(team != null)
{
    TeamSession newTeamSession = new TeamSession()
    {
        Team = team,                            
        LeagueSessionSchedule = leagueSessionSchedule
    };

    leagueSessionSchedule.TeamsSessions.Add(newTeamSession);
}
```

If you want your PK's to be automatically generated, use an appropriate type. `int` and `Guid` are by far the most commonly used types for this.

Otherwise, you're going to have to start setting your own PK values, because if you don't (and the `Id` value thus defaults to `null`), your code is going to fail when you add a second `TeamSession` object using the above code (even though you're doing everything else correctly), since PK `null` is already taken by the first entity you added to the table.

Comment: Are you sure about the cross table for EntityFramework Core? I was looking at this github issue along with the guide I posted. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368 . It would imply I would need to explicitly create the 'cross' table

Comment: @O.MeeKoh: EF Core does not yet support implicit cross tables, that is correct. It's a feature in progress. But the point about this being observed as two separate one-to-many relationships stands for _either_ version of EF. I'll amend my answer to point that out but the core of the answer remains the same.

Comment: I would agree with your post that I like solution one over solution, two, but how can I add `LeagueSessionScheduleId = leagueSessionSchedule.Id` if the new league has not yet been saved to the database. Unless I save it first and then perform this operation. I was under the impression I could add the unsved LeagueSessionSchedule to the navigational property of the unsaved TeamSession, and upon saving the new LeagueSessionSchedule EF Core would automatically, persist and add the leagueSessionScheduleId since I had the navigational property set.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh If `leagueSessionSchedule` _does_ need to be added, then the current behavior for `team` (which is throwing an error because the team already exists) is the correct approach for `leagueSessionSchedule` (which does need to be created as it does not already exist). Your intended approach for ``leagueSessionSchedule`` was not made clear from your question and I cannot account for information that you do not provide

Comment: @O.MeeKoh: Unrelated to your current code scenario, I use `Guid` for my entity IDs and have my entities set to automatically generate a new Guid in their constructor - when you do this, you _can_ actually use the FK even when you are dealing with an added-but-not-yet-saved entity. It's not directly applicable to your case right now, but it might become relevant if you do decide to move away from string-based PKs.

Comment: Hey my apologies for that. I have added the entire publish method. Does this provide more context?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205120/discussion-between-o-meekoh-and-flater).

Comment: @O.MeeKoh: The answer to the posted question remains the same regardless of your update. You were asking about an error for a team being created when it shouldn't be. What happens to the league session schedule is irrelevant for the topic at hand. If there are issues there, that should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused why you think that strings are 'undesirable' when ASP.NET Core IdentityUser object string as its type for users' ids. Which it looks like are GUIDs converted to strings.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh: It's not an issue if you don't care about automatic PK value generation. Your code as currently posted cannot work correctly as you are currently not setting the PK values yourself. I prefer to have automatically generated PKs and thus only use PK types which support auto generation, but you could also keep the strings and instead ensure that you generate the PK values yourself. `

Comment: @O.MeeKoh `IdentityUser<TPrimaryKey>` is generic and can have any (compatible) PK type you choose. `IdentityUser` indeed uses a string (presumable for maximizing compatibility with any value a developer might want to use) but it also inherently ensures automatic PK value generation - which your code currently doesn't.